# Sleeping the time difference

Tags: php, sleep

```
$lastRequestTimestamp = microtime(true);
if (microtime(true) - $lastRequestTimestamp < 1) {
  sleep(1);
}
$lastRequestTimestamp = microtime(true);

// now continue with the request ...
```

... works, but if the difference is even a few milliseconds, it sleeps for `1 second` which is significant considering the number of requests I have to make.

How do I make the script sleep only so much that there's always exactly 1 sec delay between requests, no less no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$timeDifferenceSecs = (microtime(true) - $lastRequestTimestamp);
$sleepMicrosecs = (1 - $timeDifferenceSecs)*1000000;
usleep($sleepMicrosecs);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`usleep`](http://php.net/usleep) function instead, this way you can sleep for microseconds instead of complete seconds.

Comment: So `$timeDifference = microtime(true) - $lastRequestTimestamp` and then `usleep($timeDifference)` ?

Comment: @3zzy you can't use `usleep` because it expects microseconds, where your time difference will be in seconds. `microtime` returns the time in seconds with micro second accuracy.